# Допустимо ли - "на смеси из нескольких языков"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-варианта

Или это ***из*** категорически необходимо удалить?

> Но обязанностью его было приглашать войти в ресторан, дабы
>   прохладиться и насладиться. Это он и исполнял в первую очередь.
>   Виртуозно! **На смеси из нескольких языков.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В нейтральной речи такое сочетание с предлогом воспринимается как *ошибка*, поскольку слово "смесь" в нём выполняет чисто *функциональную* роль, указывая, что языки "смешаны (перемешаны)"; при этом "смесь" **как вещество** (ср.: *сухие смеси, адская смесь...*) **не** воспринимается - беспредложное выражение "смесь (таких-то) языков" выступает как устойчивая метафора. Однако в цветастом авторском контексте такое, на мой взгляд, *можно* допустить - авторская экспрессия делает смесь особым "веществом": *смесь, составленная из того-то*. В более строгом смысле предложное сочетание исправило бы прилагательное перед "смесью" (напр. адская смесь - уже *вещество*, что позволяет отойти от стандартной идиомы "смесь языков").

Answer (score 1):

Как показывает практика, такая конструкции, как **смесь языков** очень часто используется, что я не скажу о варианте, содержащем предлог **из**. Если подумать логически, то можно прийти к выводу, что само сочетание **смесь из чего-либо** вполне уместно, но употребляется в совершенно другой ситуации:

**Он вывел в лаборатории смесь мандарина и апельсина.**

В данном примере я подчёркиваю, что мы имеем не гомогенную/гетерогенную смесь (извините за химические термины), а один фрукт (насколько я помню, клементин), получившийся в результате слияния двух разновидностей.

**Мама готовила смесь из овощей.**

Здесь, насколько я понимаю, смесь является гетерогенной и образована перемешанными частицами овощей.

Хотя, опять же, в повседневных ситуациях возможна замена первого варианта на второй.

**Надеюсь**, правильно и понятно объяснил, т.к. в ответе до конца не уверен.